# How to shrink pg_toast table?

Tags: postgresql

I am running on postgres 9.3 on mac osx and I have a database which grew out of control. I used to have table which had one column which stored large data. Then I noticed that there the db size grew up to around 19gb just because of a pg_toast table. Then I remove the mentioned column and ran vacuum in order to get the db to a smaller size again, but it remained the same. So how can I shrink the database size?

```
 SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation"
       ,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "size" 
 FROM pg_class C 
     LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace) 
 WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
 ORDER BY pg_relation_size(C.oid) DESC 
 LIMIT 20;
```

results in

```
 pg_toast.pg_toast_700305                    | 18 GB
 pg_toast.pg_toast_700305_index              | 206 MB
 public.catalog_hotelde_images               | 122 MB
 public.routes                               | 120 MB



    VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE pg_toast.pg_toast_700305;                                                                                                                                            INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_700305"
INFO:  index "pg_toast_700305_index" now contains 9601330 row versions in 26329 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU 0.06s/0.02u sec elapsed 0.33 sec.
INFO:  "pg_toast_700305": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out of 2393157 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
There were 0 unused item pointers.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU 0.06s/0.07u sec elapsed 0.37 sec.
VACUUM
```

structure of the routes table

```
id serial NOT NULL,
  origin_id integer,
  destination_id integer,
  total_time integer,
  total_distance integer,
  speed_id integer,
  uid bigint,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT routes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Comment: The toast tables store data for any "large" column. Any data type with variable length where the actual value exceeds a certain threshold will be stored there. You probably have other columns which contribute to that table size

Comment: Exactly that's what I read too about the toast table and I deleted the column which has large data, do contain only ver small values. I pasted the structure of the routes table in the original post, there you can see it.

Comment: How do you know those toast tables belong to the `routes` table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
vacuum full
```

Comment: that's it ! The tables got cleaned up. Thanks

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson, danger!  Before running `VACUUM FULL` on a production system, make sure you're aware of [potential consequences](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VACUUM_FULL).

Comment: try building a new table and just swapping with the old one for less production impact.

Comment: @hakamadare "This document is obsolete for PostgreSQL 9.0 and above. Most of the content applies only to PostgreSQL 8.4 and below."

Comment: @Bohne what is the up-to-date procedure?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg vacuum full works or "vacuum full table_name" also works. As linuxfreaks mentions, rebuilding the table, dropping the old table and renaming the rebuilt one back to the original name also works.

There's nothing too fancy about any of it, the vacuum full command is basically "locking" the table, then doing a "defrag" (simplification) on it. The rebuild is "refreshing all data" which is faster, but it too has problems on a production system as your OLD table data might get modified during the process. If the system is down, either way works fine.

Answer (score 13):

You can use one of the two types of vacuuming: **standard** or **full**.

standard:

```
VACUUM table_name;
```

full:

```
VACUUM FULL table_name;
```

Keep in mind that VACUUM FULL locks the table it is working on until it's finished.

You may want to perform standard vacuum more frequently on your tables which have frequent upload/delete activity, it may not give you as much space as vacuum full does but you will be able to run operations like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE and it will take less time to complete.

In my case, when pg_toast (along with other tables) got out of control, standard VACUUM made a slight difference but was not enough. I used VACUUM FULL to reclaim more disk space which was very slow on large relations. I decided to [tune autovacuum](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/autovacuum-tuning-basics/) and use standard VACUUM more often on my tables which are updated frequently.

If you need to use VACUUM FULL, you should do it when your users are less active.
Also, do not turn off autovacuum.

You can get some additional information by adding *verbose* to your commands:

```
VACUUM FULL VERBOSE table_name;
```